# Aggregate rows using a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe is like this:

```
*Ccusto*
ABC
CDE
FEG
Internet
```

I want it:

```
*Ccusto*
Other
Internet
```

Using `dplyr`, I'm trying:

```
df %>%
mutate(Ccusto = recode(Ccusto != "Internet", "Other"))
```

And although `Ccusto` is a `factor`, I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("recode") : 
  no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Comment: `ifelse(Ccusto != "Internet", "Other", Ccusto)`

Comment: Thanks, that works, but converts the factor into a character

Comment: The levels of your factor will change, so you will need to redefine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Ccusto = case_when(
                    Ccusto == 'Internet' ~ 'Internet',
                    TRUE ~ 'Other'
                  ),
         Ccusto = factor(Ccusto))
#    Ccusto
#1    Other
#2    Other
#3    Other
#4 Internet
```

Another `dplyr/forcats` way, maybe more complicated. First get the current levels from the factor column, then create a vector of new levels, `nms`. Base function `setNames` will create a named vector of the new factor levels. The three `!!!` are described in the last example of [`help('forcats::fct_recode')`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_recode.html).

```
levels <- levels(df$Ccusto)
nms <- c("Other", "Internet")[(levels == "Internet") + 1L]

df %>%
  mutate(Ccusto = fct_recode(Ccusto, !!!setNames(levels, nms)))
```

The output is the same as above and was, therefore, omited.

**Data**

```
Ccusto <- scan(what = character(), text = '
ABC
CDE
FEG
Internet')
df <- data.frame(Ccusto, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Comment: OK @Rui Barradas isso funciona melhor, obrigado!

Comment: @NunoNogueira E há outro modo, veja a edição./And there's another way, now. See the edit.

Comment: I'm always learning, even basic stuff like this may become pretty complicated sometimes. Forcats looks interesting!